# How to select multiple rows and return them as JSON in one column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this data in MySQL that looks like this (the actual data is different but I just to make it easer)

Note: children column is JSON

```
    SELECT id, name, children FROM people;
```

| id | name | children |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Jack | ["5", "3"] |
| 3 | John | Null |
| 5 | Sara | Null |

children can NOT have other children, children can NOT be in a different table because the data is similar and I need all the people at once, and I don't want to access the database for every child

The data should look like this after SELECT:

| id | name | children |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Jack | [{'id': '5', 'name': 'Sara'},{'id': '3', 'name': 'John'}] |
| 3 | John | Null |
| 5 | Sara | Null |

#### is it possible, how can I do it ?

#### is there a better way to do this (not another table)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest to change your table layout to a parent->child relationship with a parent_id column.

The current layout mixes json string values with integer column values. When the table grows larger you will probably run into perfomance problems, too (just a guess currently).

The other approach would be:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jbVqtZjZbmPAZ42S8A8fbT/1

```
CREATE TABLE people (id INT, name TEXT, parent_id INT);
INSERT INTO people (id, name, parent_id)
VALUES 
(2,'Jack', Null),
(3,'John', 2),
(5,'Sara', 2)
;
```

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, 

(SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', pc.id, 'name', pc.name)) FROM people pc
WHERE pc.parent_id=p.id) AS children

FROM people p
```

Comment: Thank you, the answer is really helpful. From the official MySQL docs I didn't right away realize that `JSON_ARRAYAGG` function can actually accept `JSON_OBJECT` expression as an argument.